# Loop through URL, group json results

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to parse the json data for multiple campsites by looping through a url and using a variable for the campsite numbers. I would like to group the results by the UnitId then but the loop does not see to run for each campsite.

I Have tried doing this using requests then after reading it seemed to be better to use pandas but I just can't get it to work.

Here is my code example. For some reason only results for UnitId 5098 show and the filter won't work.

```
# Is one of these campsites available
# Unit 5095
# Unit 5096
# Unit 5097
# Unit 5099

import requests
import pandas as pd

result = []
for i in range(5095, 5099):
    resp = requests.get("https://calirdr.usedirect.com/rdr/rdr/fd/availability/getbyunit/"+str(i)+"/startdate/2020-11-01/nights/30/true?")

result.extend(resp.json())

df = pd.DataFrame(result)

df.groupby(['UnitId', 'StartTime', 'IsFree', 'IsWalkin'])
print(df.groupby(['UnitId', 'StartTime', 'IsFree', 'IsWalkin']).groups)
```

JSON data results from my code.

```
{(5098, '2020-11-01T00:00:00', False, False): [0], (5098, '2020-11-02T00:00:00', False, False): [1], (5098, '2020-11-03T00:00:00', False, False): [2], (5098, '2020-11-04T00:00:00', False, False): [3], (5098, '2020-11-05T00:00:00', False, False): [4], (5098, '2020-11-06T00:00:00', False, False): [5], (5098, '2020-11-07T00:00:00', False, False): [6], (5098, '2020-11-08T00:00:00', False, False): [7], (5098, '2020-11-09T00:00:00', False, False): [8], (5098, '2020-11-10T00:00:00', False, False): [9], (5098, '2020-11-11T00:00:00', False, False): [10], (5098, '2020-11-12T00:00:00', False, False): [11], (5098, '2020-11-13T00:00:00', False, False): [12], (5098, '2020-11-14T00:00:00', False, False): [13], (5098, '2020-11-15T00:00:00', False, False): [14], (5098, '2020-11-16T00:00:00', False, False): [15], (5098, '2020-11-17T00:00:00', False, False): [16], (5098, '2020-11-18T00:00:00', False, False): [17], (5098, '2020-11-19T00:00:00', False, False): [18], (5098, '2020-11-20T00:00:00', False, False): [19], (5098, '2020-11-21T00:00:00', False, False): [20], (5098, '2020-11-22T00:00:00', False, False): [21], (5098, '2020-11-23T00:00:00', False, False): [22], (5098, '2020-11-24T00:00:00', False, False): [23], (5098, '2020-11-25T00:00:00', False, False): [24], (5098, '2020-11-26T00:00:00', False, False): [25], (5098, '2020-11-27T00:00:00', False, False): [26], (5098, '2020-11-28T00:00:00', False, False): [27], (5098, '2020-11-29T00:00:00', False, False): [28], (5098, '2020-11-30T00:00:00', False, False): [29]}
```

Results I would like to have printed. This is just an example, it's hard to find campsites that are actually available. Thank you all for your help. This is just a hobby I'm by no means a programmer but its pretty cool especially Python. Thank you.

```
(5095, '2020-11-05T00:00:00', False, False):
(5096, '2020-11-12T00:00:00', False, False):
(5099, '2020-11-25T00:00:00', False, False):
```

Comment: You're getting `resp` in the loop but then the next loop iteration immediately replaces it, so when the loop is over, `resp` is just the final one.

Comment: any idea how I can  fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to indent `result.extend(resp.json())` into the `for loop` body. Also, you might want consider using `filter()`. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

result = []
for unit_id in range(5095, 5099):
    resp = requests.get(
        f"https://calirdr.usedirect.com/rdr/rdr/fd/"
        f"availability/getbyunit/{unit_id}/startdate/2020-11-01/nights/30/true?").json()
    result.extend(resp)

filter_by = ['UnitId', 'StartTime', 'IsFree', 'IsWalkin']
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df = df.filter(items=filter_by)
df['StartTime'] = df['StartTime'].apply(lambda d: datetime.fromisoformat(d).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
df = df[df['IsFree']]
print(tabulate(df, headers=filter_by))
```

Output:

```
      UnitId  StartTime    IsFree    IsWalkin
--  --------  -----------  --------  ----------
60      5097  2020-11-01   True      False
78      5097  2020-11-19   True      False
87      5097  2020-11-28   True      False
```

Comment: AMAZING!! that works great. Is it possible to only print the results if IsFree = True and IsWalkin = False?

Comment: Sure you can! I've updated the answer. By the way, if you find the answer useful please up-vote and/or accept it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been working on this for weeks. It's not easy when you try to program as a hobby but it's sure useful to do task for you.  Take care.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been working on this for weeks. It's not easy when you try to program as a hobby but it's sure useful to do task for you.  Take care.

Comment: I see you added where 'isFree' how do I add 'IsWalkin' must be False.

Comment: Well, you don't really have to do that because the `isFree == True` already handles the other case, as in the output. However, you if want to *reverse* the condition, say, show all units that are `isFree == False` just do this `df = [~df['isFree']]`